# Address field module autofill city and state when zip code is entered

Tags: 7, ajax, entities

In the United States, cities are split up by a unique 5 digit zip codes (postal code). This postal code in turn tells what city and state it is from. Therefore it is redundant to type the city and state.

**Is there a way, with the [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module, to autofill the city and state if a postal code is submited?**

This then leads to the second question, **how to force a correct postal code entry**. By default a user can type any text and it will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Javascript code that uses zipcodeapi.com API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // IMPORTANT: Fill in your client key
    var clientKey = "js-9qZHzu2Flc59Eq5rx10JdKERovBlJp3TQ3ApyC4TOa3tA8U7aVRnFwf41RpLgtE7";

    var cache = {};
    var container = $("#example1");
    var errorDiv = container.find("div.text-error");

    /** Handle successful response */
    function handleResp(data)
    {
        // Check for error
        if (data.error_msg)
            errorDiv.text(data.error_msg);
        else if ("city" in data)
        {
            // Set city and state
            container.find("input[name='city']").val(data.city);
            container.find("input[name='state']").val(data.state);
        }
    }

    // Set up event handlers
    container.find("input[name='zipcode']").on("keyup change", function() {
        // Get zip code
        var zipcode = $(this).val().substring(0, 5);
        if (zipcode.length == 5 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(zipcode))
        {
            // Clear error
            errorDiv.empty();

            // Check cache
            if (zipcode in cache)
            {
                handleResp(cache[zipcode]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Build url
                var url = "http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/"+clientKey+"/info.json/" + zipcode + "/radians";

                // Make AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    "url": url,
                    "dataType": "json"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    handleResp(data);

                    // Store in cache
                    cache[zipcode] = data;
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    if (data.responseText && (json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText)))
                    {
                        // Store in cache
                        cache[zipcode] = json;

                        // Check for error
                        if (json.error_msg)
                            errorDiv.text(json.error_msg);
                    }
                    else
                        errorDiv.text('Request failed.');
                });
            }
        }
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

//]]>

You can see an example here - http://www.zipcodeapi.com/Examples#example1

Since the question is how to autofill a valid city and state based on the user entering a zipcode first, the above Javascript code does that. Click on the example above to see how it works.

Comment: What does this code do, and how does it answer the actual question?

Comment: The question was how to autofill a valid city and state based on the user entering a zipcode first.  The code is Javascript that does that. Click on the example above to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can develop your own custom module using dependencies on address field .

1. You need to define a server function that will return the city and state in JSON based on a zip code.
2. Subscribe to change, keyup and input events on an input field.
3. Define a JavaScript function that will call the server function using AJAX. On the success function, you set the fields using the response.

Helping code

```
$("#txtZipCode").bind("change keyup input", function (e) {
        var field = $(this);
        if (field.val().length === 5) {
            showLocation(field.val());
        }
        else
            showLocation("");
    });

function showLocation(zipCodeValue) {
    var txtCity = $("#city");
    var txtState = $("#state");
    if (zipCodeValue.toString().length != 5) {
        txtCity.val("");
        txtState.val("");
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Location/GetZipCode",
            data:
                {
                    zipCodeNumber: zipCodeValue
                },
            success: function (data) {
                    txtCity.val(data.City);
                    txtState.val(data.State);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be **[Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill)** will help you to achieve this functionality. There is a remark in project page about this.

> **Addressfield**: Addressfield needs some additional processing in order to be loaded. A sub-module is included to make it work. Enable **"Entity reference autofill addressfield"** and you're good to go.

I didnt tested this, just found while searching.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: how it can fetch city name or state when it is not exist in database it can fetched by depend on zipcode

Comment: check [Autocomplete By Zip Code](http://www.bluefrogdevelopment.com/node/11). here explains it with a custom module.

Comment: thank you Abin for the helpful link! unfortunately i don't have the skills to create that module. If anyone is willing to help me figure it out that would be great!

Comment: itz not a big deal tim, u can create that custom module. there a lots of tutorials available

Answer (score 0):

You might check out this new module from Lush and give it a review in the process.

Address Field Lookup: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/danielmrichards/2580615